# Aggregate date Range Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Dear,

I'am trying to count value in my mongo db but the aggregation return empty array.

My query look like this:

```
Order.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    '$match': {
                        createdAt : {
                            '$gte' : new Date("2017-11-29").setHours(14,43,0,0),
                            '$lt' : new Date()
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        count: {
                            $sum: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        ).exec().then(r => {
            console.log(r); // []
        });
```

An other (and dirty) query works fine:

```
Order.find({
            createdAt : {
                '$gte' : new Date("2017-11-29").setHours(14,43,0,0),
                '$lt' : new Date()
            }
        }).exec().then(orders => {
            console.log(orders.length);// 1463

        })
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not

```
Order.count({
            createdAt : {
                '$gte' : new Date("2017-11-29").setHours(14,43,0,0),
                '$lt' : new Date()
            }
        }).exec().then(count=> {
            console.log(count);// 1463

        })
```

Comment: Thanks, It's not explain why I can not perform aggregation but it answers to my short term issue

Comment: I will check for this issue definitely and update my answer accordingly

Comment: @Shubham did you check??

Comment: check this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768327/mongodb-using-lean-on-aggregate-function/47771419#47771419
date needs to be converted in a datatype ISODate but in aggregation it send date as string in and when you use find it converts date to ISODate