# MongoDB: Using lean on aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use the `lean()` option in order to speed up my queries. But when adding it to a query like this:

```
Pets.aggregate({ $match: { 'Name': 'Floofkins', 'lastMealDate': {$gt: today}}}, function (err, pets){
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).json({'error': err});
    console.log('Could not fetch pets: ' + err);
    return;
  }
    petsHadMealsToday = pets.length;
}).lean();
```

All I get is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lean' of undefined` although `pets.length` returns the number of pets that matched the query.

<s>If I'd remove the `match` option however and run something like below, it works like a charm.</s>

```
Pets.aggregate({ 'Name': 'Floofkins', 'lastMealDate': {$gt: today}}, function (err, pets){
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({'error': err});
        console.log('Could not fetch pets: ' + err);
        return;
      }
        petsHadMealsToday = pets.length;
    }).lean();
```

I guess I'm missing some fundamental point about how to use `match` and such, so feel free to educate me!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After reading a bit, this is my take on the answer to my question:

`lean()` is not needed on an `aggregate` function as the documents returned are plain JavaScript objects, and not Mongoose objects. This is because any shape of document can be returned. [Source](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate).

Therefore adding `lean()` to an `aggregate` function will generate an error since there is nothing to perform the `lean()` function upon.

Comment: but response returning bson id also

Answer (score 17):

No need to lean pipeline output . Aggregate output is already lean , using mongoose too 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate

because output of aggregate pipeline is not a mongoose document

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still don't understand why it would complain about being undefined in one case (when using match) and work without a hitch in the other, (when not using match).

Comment: Actually I have never tried code like your second snippet , all I can say that may be mongoose is doing something in this case but in case , I will check and update my answer

Comment: I'm so sorry, I must have gotten things mixed up as I've now discovered that the second example doesn't work either. I'll update my original post.